# What is the correct usage of the Seam @Transactional annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, seam

I'm a bit confused about the meaning of values used in the [@Transactional](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.1.CR1/api/org/jboss/seam/annotations/Transactional.html) annotation, specifically [@TransactionPropagationType](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.1.CR1/api/org/jboss/seam/annotations/TransactionPropagationType.html). Perhaps Gavin thought it would be obvious enough from the name of each enum type and decided not to document the actual meaning... Be that as it may I have no clue what any of the following actually mean: MANDATORY, NEVER, REQUIRED, SUPPORTS. Anyone out there who does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These propogation types are almost the same in different declarative transaction management implementations (EJB3, Spring and Seam). Curiously, they are documented in  javadoc only [in Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html).

Comment: also, it looks like Seam 3 has better documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/persistence/latest/api/org/jboss/seam/persistence/transaction/TransactionPropagation.html

Comment: Updated Javadoc Link to current version

Answer (score 5):

From the book Seam in Action the enum tyes mean that :

REQUIRED Indicates that a transaction is required to execute the method. If a transaction
isn’t active, Seam will begin a new transaction. This is the default type.

SUPPORTS Indicates that the method is permitted to execute in the presence of an
active transaction, but it won’t begin a transaction if one isn’t active.

MANDATORY Indicates that an active transaction is required to execute the method.
A runtime exception is thrown if a transaction isn’t already in progress.

NEVER Indicates that a transaction shouldn’t be active when this method is called.
A runtime exception will be thrown if a transaction is active.

Hope this helps ;-)

Answer (score 0):

axtavt was right, the meaning is the same as in Spring. The [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/persistence/latest/api/) for Seam 3 is more thorough, so the [TransactionPropagation enum is better explained](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/persistence/latest/api/org/jboss/seam/persistence/transaction/TransactionPropagation.html)